# How to find the imporper data that cause ORA-01436

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data, recursive-query, hierarchical-query

I have a query to see the parent and child hierarchical list of data. On running the below query i got the error `ORA-01436`.

```
SELECT ParentPropertyRSN, CONNECT_BY_ROOT PropertyRSN as PropertyRSN,
   LEVEL, SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(ParentPropertyRSN, '/') Path
FROM Property
   CONNECT BY PRIOR PropertyRSN = ParentPropertyRSN
   order by level desc;
```

So I added `NOCYCLE` in the `CONNECT BY` clause and got the full list of data with its hierarchical path

Now what I need is a query to get the list of rows that have inaccurate data whih cause `ORA-01436`.

Comment: Please post some test data, as text no images, and the expected results. In this case include data that gives the error and some that doesn't (if possible). Further indicate the expected results and indicate those that gives the error.  You may also want to review [ask].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should indeed use `NOCYCLE` to avoid the infinite loop. On top of that, you can use `CONNECT_BY_ISCYCLE` to identify the offending row(s):

```
SELECT 
    ParentPropertyRSN, 
    CONNECT_BY_ROOT PropertyRSN as PropertyRSN,
    LEVEL, 
    SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(ParentPropertyRSN, '/') Path,
    CONNECT_BY_ISCYCLE Has_Cycle
FROM Property
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR PropertyRSN = ParentPropertyRSN
ORDER BY level desc;
```

From [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/pseudocolumns001.htm):

> The `CONNECT_BY_ISCYCLE` pseudocolumn returns `1` if the current row has a child which is also its ancestor. Otherwise it returns `0`.
>
> You can specify `CONNECT_BY_ISCYCLE` only if you have specified the `NOCYCLE` parameter of the `CONNECT BY` clause. `NOCYCLE` enables Oracle to return the results of a query that would otherwise fail because of a `CONNECT BY` loop in the data.

Comment: i got the result, but what to do If i want to see only the offending rows

Comment: @SuwaidAkbar: well you can just turn this query to a subquery, and then filter on `HasCycle` in the outer query.